# Fetching a json_encoded array exhausts memory

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have two arrays from form inputs that I am trying to combine and store in a single database cell. I am able to do this, but when trying to retrieve it, it gives a fatal error of exhausting the memory limit.

I am inserting a main slider basically that has additional slides within it. Kind of. I don't want to create individual sql tables, but maybe I need to.

My memory is at 256mb, I know I could increase it more but I'd rather figure out why it is so large.

So my Inputs are coming from:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <label class="label-top" for="scroll-content[]">Scroll Text #1</label>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="scroll-content[]" id="scroll-content-"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="slide-number[]" value="1">
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="form-group">
  <label class="label-top" for="scroll-content[]">Scroll Text #2:</label>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="scroll-content[]" id="scroll-content-"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="slide-number[]" value="2">
</fieldset>
```

Inserting:

```
function add_new_scroll($dir, $plugin_id) {

    // configure content array
    $num = $_POST['slide-number'];
    $array = $_POST['scroll-content'];
    $combined = array_combine($num, $array);

    $content = json_encode($combined);

    // global connection
    global $conn;
    wj_connect();

    // sql
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `scroll_text` (`scroll_order`, `num_slides`, `scroll_title`, `scroll_slug`, `scroll_content`)
                VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    `scroll_order` = VALUES(`scroll_order`),
                    `num_slides` = VALUES(`num_slides`),
                    `scroll_title` = VALUES(`scroll_title`),
                    `scroll_slug` = VALUES(`scroll_slug`),
                    `scroll_content` = VALUES(`scroll_content`)";

    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {

        $stmt->bind_param("iisss", $ansp_order, $ansp_num_slides, $ansp_title, $ansp_slug, $ansp_content);

        // set params
        $ansp_order = 0;
        $ansp_num_slides = 1;
        $ansp_title = $_POST['scroll-title'];
        $ansp_slug = $_POST['scroll-slug'];
        $ansp_content = $content;

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

    } else {
        echo 'Scroll Text not added.';
    }

    $conn->close();
    header("Location: ". $dir . "/scroll-text-admin.php?plug_id=" . $plugin_id . "&type=edit&slug=" . $ansp_slug);
}
```

Stores like:

```
{"1":"<p>1<\/p>","2":"<p>2<\/p>"}
```

Retrieving:

```
function return_scroll() {

    // global connection
    global $conn;
    wj_connect();

    // sql
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `scroll_order`, `num_slides`, `scroll_title`, `scroll_slug`, `scroll_content`
                FROM `scroll_text` WHERE `scroll_slug` = ? LIMIT 1";

    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $rsp_slug);
        $rsp_slug = $_GET['slug'];

        $stmt->execute();

        // bind results
        $stmt->bind_result($rsr_id, $rsr_order, $rsr_num_slides, $rsr_title, $rsr_slug, $rsr_content);

        $scroll = array(
            'id' => $rsr_id,
            'order' => $rsr_order,
            'num_slides' => $rsr_num_slides,
            'title' => $rsr_title,
            'slug' => $rsr_slug,
            'content' => $rsr_content
            );

        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
    }

    $conn->close();

    return $scroll;
}
```

Error!:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in /home/wonderadmin/public_html/wj-admin/plugins/scroll-text/scroll-text.php on line 199
```

Comment: Which line is 199?

Comment: The bind_result()

// bind results
$stmt->bind_result($rsr_id, $rsr_order, $rsr_num_slides, $rsr_title, $rsr_slug, $rsr_content);

Answer (score 0):

Well my MySQL database row type was longtext. Changed it to mediumtext and I'm fine. Embarrassing.

Comment: Nice catch ;) By the way, if you have DBA working with your team, you might want to book some time with him to review your queries or BD structure you've built. Believe, he might bring very useful optimization tips.